# how to update table based on another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

i have 2 tables as fallow:

```
users
zip      state      city
89012    
45869     0
....


zips
zip      state      city
89012    NV         lv
45869    MI         ca
....
```

i would like to update `users: state and city` with the `state and city` from `zips` based on the `zip` from the `users` table in an efficient way

the `city` in `users` table is empty but the `state` can also be `0` or empty

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you trying to update all of the existing rows in bulk?

If so, here's one way to do the update:

```
update users u
  inner join zips z on z.zip = u.zip
set u.state = z.state,
  u.city = z.city;
```

Comment: there should be the condition that `(city <> '' and state <> '') or  (city <> '' and state <> '0')` or something like this

Comment: Certainly you can refine the query to not replace good data with bad, etc depending on your requirements. I was just working from the requirements you gave in the original question.