# Update foreign key column with another table's primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I need to update a column in one table based on a column's value in another table.  This question has been asked at least a couple times here and every answer with high votes states to join the two tables and set the value of a column in one table based on the value of the applicable column in the other table:

- [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)
- [Update table based on another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023367/update-table-based-on-another-table)
- [How to update table based on another table column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200246/how-to-update-table-based-on-another-table-column)
- [Update based on another table result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150685/update-based-on-another-table-result)
- [how to update table based on another table in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977222/how-to-update-table-based-on-another-table-in-mysql)
- [how to update table based on another table in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977222/how-to-update-table-based-on-another-table-in-mysql)
- [Update Relational table based on another table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480203/update-relational-table-based-on-another-table-in-mysql)
- [How to update a column with another tables columns value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849774/how-to-update-a-column-with-another-tables-columns-value)

It doesn't seem to work for me, and either I am not seeing things correct or my conditions are different.

**EDIT 1**.  I didn't show it, but `supertype` also has an `accounts_id` column, and think that is the column I will be joining on.

I have a supertype and subtype table where the subtype table includes a second field called `supertype_id` which stores a supertype record's PK (schema shown below).

I need to update `subtype.supertype_id` for a given subtype record (i.e. `subtype.id=123`) with a supertype table's PK based on some other attribute of the supertype table (i.e. `supertype.publicId=321`).

So, I originally thought I would need some sort of JOIN, however, didn't update any rows as the JOIN doesn't yet exist.

```
UPDATE subtype
INNER JOIN supertype ON supertype.id=subtype.id
SET subtype.supertype_id=supertype.id
WHERE subtype.id=123 AND supertype.idPublic=321;

UPDATE subtype
INNER JOIN supertype ON supertype.id=subtype.id AND supertype.idPublic=321
SET subtype.supertype_id=supertype.id
WHERE subtype.id=123;
```

I could likely do something like the following, however, question doing so as it differs from all highly voted answers and it also attempts to set `suptype.supertype_id` to `NULL` if `supertype` doesn't have a record with the given `idPublic` which will result in a foreign key constraint.

```
UPDATE subtype SET supertype_id = SELECT id FROM superset WHERE idPublic=321;
```

How should this be implemented?

**EDIT 2**.  Maybe something like this?

```
UPDATE suptype sbt
INNER JOIN supertype spt1 ON spt1.id=sbt.id
INNER JOIN supertype spt2 ON spt2.accounts_id=spt1.accounts_id
SET sbt.supertype_id =sbt2.id
WHERE sbt2.idPublic=321 AND sbt.id=123;
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE supertype (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  publicId INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX publicIdIdx (publicId ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE subtype (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  supertype_id INT NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_subtype_supertype1_idx (supertype_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_subtype_supertype
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES supertype (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_subtype_supertype1
    FOREIGN KEY (supertype_id)
    REFERENCES supertype (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You are joining the two tables on subtype.id = supertype.id, but you also have a column subtype.supertype_id. Are you sure you didn't mean to join on this column?

Comment: @JacobH  If I do, there won't be a JOIN until after the update, so the update will never happen.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're trying to do. Is PublicId a unique value for all the supertype records? That's your join predicate here.

Comment: Sample data, before and after, would make it much easier to understand what you are trying to do.  As it is now, I can't tell if your problem is in your query, your data, or how you've phrased your question.

Comment: @JacobH  `idPublic` is unique for all records with a given `account_id`.

Comment: Also, supertype.id = subtype.id, what is the purpose of also having subtype.supertype_id?  It seems redundant; if supertype.id = subtype.id, wouldn't subtype.id always be the same value as subtype.supertype_id?

Comment: @WesH  the part about `idPublic`, `account_id`, and that the two tables have a `1-to-1` relationship  is all real.  I don't believe other data is relevant and was concerned that it would obscure the issue at hand.

Comment: @WesH  No, it is a different record.  The tables represent real energy meters and virtual energy meters.  For instance, I have real meters `Building A Meter` and virtual meter `Building A 12 Month Meter`.  Both have a record in the supertype table who's PK is joined to each's PK, however, the subtype table for the virtual meter needs to reference the real `Building A Meter`.  While I am happy to discuss this part, I don't think it is relevant to what I am asking, but I suppose providing it is best as it removes the "why are you doing this" part.

Comment: @user1032531 You need to provide sample data along with schema for all of the tables and columns that you think might be involved.  The information that you've provided is not enough to answer your questions or discuss your suggestions.  Give us executable scripts documenting what you've tried, the result you want, and the result you're getting.  Putting it in SQLFiddle is very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to SELECT that particular value.  If you had a recipe that stored the type of flour used as an id from a table of flours, but you have a form that allowed a user to select the type, not the type id, you would convert the user's selection to the foreign table's id something like this.

```
UPDATE TableRecipe
SET BakeMinutes = 90,
    FlourTypeID = (SELECT FlourTypeID FROM TableFlourTypes WHERE Type = 'AllPurpose')
WHERE RecipeID= 34
```

Comment: Thanks John,  Looking over what I originally posted, realize I wasn't very clear, don't anymore recall what I was thinking, and am going to go with this!